# how to check if i have mongodb installed on my computer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest

I'm trying to create a RESTful API using Node.js and MongoDB for the first time. I'm new to back end programming.
For some reason am getting this error

```
    module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './routes/api'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\rest\server.js:15:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I am unsure whether MongoDB is installed correctly, but I don't know how to check that.

Please help me, either with the error or how I can to check that I have installed MongoDB correctly.

Here is my `server.js`

```
// DEPENDENCIES
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test');

// EXPRESS
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// ROUTES
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

// START SERVER
app.listen(3000);
console.log('API is working on port 3000')
```

Comment: here is my server.js

Comment: // DEPENDENCIES   
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// MongoDB          
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test');
// EXPRESS               
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

// ROUTES            
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

// START SERVER                
app.listen(3000);
console.log('API is working on port 3000');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to run MongoDB on your machine use command `mongod` (if you have a path to mongod.exe in your System PATH Variable)

Install all dependencies for your project with `npm install express mongoose body-parser`

And `Error: Cannot find module './routes/api'` Where your `api.js` file ?

After that you can run your server use `node server.js`

Since I do not see your file `api.js` I write it myself for clarity

server.js

```
// DEPENDENCIES
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test');

// EXPRESS
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// ROUTES
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

// START SERVER
app.listen(3000);
console.log('API is working on port 3000')
```

routes/api.js

```
module.exports = function(app, res) {
    res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/routes/index.html');
}
```

routes/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Node.js</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer.  i couldn`t vote it up coz im still new here and not allowed to vote before 15 reputation  :)

Comment: @shireefkhatab I am glad that I could help you. You can also choose the answer as a solution http://i.imgur.com/VDgepIs.png You do not need a reputation for that

Comment: Where can i  choose the answer as a solution?

Comment: @shireefkhatab or you can see on meta stackoverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done.. so sorry for late response

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are on Windows:

- Check in your program files in C:\ to look for a Mongo folder

To use mongo, you need to start a server on your machine. 
To do this, launch mongod.exe in the mongo folder you have found previously.

It should work after the server is started!

Comment: now it is giving me this errorevents.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)

Comment: at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (C:\xampp\htdocs\rest\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\rest\server.js:20:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3

Comment: i had to restart the computer and the xamp